# Creating a shell in C that handles redirection and pipes

Tags: c, shell

The following function successfully executes any command that doesn't contain pipes, so don't worry about the weird functions. These work. The problem I am having is that whenever I execute any command like the following:

```
cat file.txt | grep string
```

the command is successfully executed, but it remains idle, so somehow it gets stuck and no other command can execute. why is this happening?. I think it has something to do with the way I use pipe, dup and fork, so try to approach the problem from these functions.  I know you may be arguing that this code doesn't work for other commands with pipes, but I  just want to get this particular example to work and to do so I just redirect STDIN to the open file in the first iteration.

```
    int myshell_execute(struct processNode* list, int a)
    {

      struct processNode* myList = list; // next node to be handled
      int pipefd[2];
      int in=0;
      if (pipe(pipefd) == -1) {
            perror("pipe");
            myshell_exit(-1);
        }

      while(myList != NULL)
      {

      char* program = myList->program;  // Get the program to be executed
      char ** program_args = myList->program_arguments; // get the programs and arguments to be executed
      char ** redirection_string = myList->redirection; //get the part of the command that contains redirection
      int *status;
      int* stdout;
      int stdout_num = 1;
      stdout = &stdout_num;
      int fileDescriptor;
      pid_t pid;

        if(strcmp(program,"cd") == 0)
        {
          return myshell_cd(program_args);
        }
        else if (strcmp(program,"exit") == 0)
        {
          return myshell_exit(0);
        }


      pid = fork();

      if(pid == 0)
      {  

        if(in == 1)
        {
         close(pipefd[1]);
         dup2(pipefd[0],0);
         close(pipefd[0]);
        }

        if(sizeOfLine(redirection_string) != 0)
        {
        redirectionHandler(redirection_string,stdout); // This works. This just handles redirection properly
        }

        if(*stdout == 1 && myList->next !=NULL)
        { 
          close(pipefd[0]);
          dup2(pipefd[1],STDOUT_FILENO); // with this
          close(pipefd[1]);
        }
        if(execvp(program,program_args) !=-1)
        {
          perror("myshell:");
          myshell_exit(-1);
        }
        else{
          myshell_exit(0);
        }
      }
      else if (pid <0)
        {
          perror("myshell: ");
          myshell_exit(-1);
       }
      else
       {
         wait(status);  

       }
       in = 1;
      myList = myList->next;

      }
    }
```

new solution:

```
int helper_execute(int in, int out, char* program, char ** program_args, char *redirection)
    {
      pid_t pid;

      if ((pid = fork ()) == 0)
        {
          if (in != 0)
            {
              dup2 (in, 0);
              close (in);
            }

          if (out != 1)
            {
              dup2 (out, 1);
              close (out);
            }

          redirectionHandler(redirection);
          return execvp (program, program_args);
        }

      return pid;
    }


        int myshell_execute(struct processNode* list, int a)
        {
          int i;
          pid_t pid;
          int in, fd [2];
          struct processNode*new_list = list;
          char ** newProgram = new_list->program_arguments;
          char ** redirection = new_list->redirection;
          char * program = new_list->program;

          /* The first process should get its input from the original file descriptor 0.  */
          in = 0;

          /* Note the loop bound, we spawn here all, but the last stage of the pipeline.  */
          while(new_list->next != NULL)
            {
              pipe (fd);
              /* f [1] is the write end of the pipe, we carry `in` from the prev iteration.  */
              helper_execute (in, fd [1],program,newProgram,redirection);

              /* No need for the write end of the pipe, the child will write here.  */
              close (fd [1]);

              /* Keep the read end of the pipe, the next child will read from there.  */
              in = fd [0];

              new_list = new_list->next;
            }

          /* Last stage of the pipeline - set stdin be the read end of the previous pipe
             and output to the original file descriptor 1. */  
          if (in != 0)
            dup2 (in, 0);

          /* Execute the last stage with the current process. */
          char* lastProgram = new_list->program;
          char ** lastRedirection = new_list->redirection;
          char * lastPrArguments = new_list->program_arguments;
          redirectionHandler(redirection);
          return execvp (lastProgram, lastPrArguments);
        }

        int main() {
          int i=0;
          char **input;
          struct processNode* list;
          int tracker = 0;

          while ((input = getline()) != EOF) {  
              list = create_list(input);
              myshell_execute(list,0);
          }

          return 0;
        }
```

The only problem with this solution is that as soon as one command is executed, the main immediately detects the end of the file, so it exits the shell.

Answer (score 0):

This is because

1. your parent process also holds the pipe open,
2. just after forking you call `wait`. If your first process (`cat`) fills its output pipe and there is not any process yet available to consume the read end of the pipe then the process stalls forever.

It would look like this:

```
#define MAX_PIPE_LEN 256
int myshell_execute(struct processNode* list, int a)
{
    /* fd0 are the input and output descriptor for this command. fd1
       are the input and output descriptor for the next command in the
       pipeline. */
    int fd0[2] = { STDIN_FILENO, STDOUT_FILENO },
        fd1[2] = { -1, -1 };
    pid_t pids[MAX_PIPE_LEN] = { 0 };
    int pipe_len;
    struct processNode* myList; // next node to be handled
    int status;
    int failed = 0;
    for (pipe_len = 0, myList = list;
         pipe_len < MAX_PIPE_LEN && myList != NULL;
         pipe_len++, myList = myList->next) {
        char* program = myList->program;  // Get the program to be executed
        char ** program_args = myList->program_arguments; // get the programs and arguments to be executed
        char ** redirection_string = myList->redirection; //get the part of the command that contains redirection
        if(strcmp(program,"cd") == 0) {
            return myshell_cd(program_args);
        }
        else if (strcmp(program,"exit") == 0) {
            return myshell_exit(0);
        }
        if (myList->next != NULL) {
            /* The output of this command is piped into the next one */
            int pipefd[2];
            if (pipe(pipefd) == -1) {
                perror("pipe failed");
                failed = 1;
                break;
            }
            fd1[0] = pipefd[0];
            fd1[1] = fd0[1];
            fd0[1] = pipefd[1];
        }
        pids[pipe_len] = fork();
        if (pids[pipe_len] < 0) {
            perror("error: fork failed");
            failed = 1;
            break;
        }
        if (pids[pipe_len] == 0) {  
            if (fd0[0] != STDIN_FILENO) {
                if (dup2(fd0[0], STDIN_FILENO) == -1) {
                    perror("error: dup2 input failed");
                    abort();
                }
                close(fd0[0]);
            }
            if (fd0[1] != STDOUT_FILENO) {
                if (dup2(fd0[1], STDOUT_FILENO) == -1) {
                    perror("error: dup2 outut failed");
                    abort();
                }
                close(fd0[1]);
            }
            if (fd1[0] >= 0) {
                close(fd1[0]);
            }
            if (fd1[1] >= 0) {
                close(fd1[1]);
            }
            if(sizeOfLine(redirection_string) != 0) {
                redirectionHandler(redirection_string,stdout); // This works. This just handles redirection properly
            }
            execvp(program, program_args);
            perror("error: execvp failed");
            abort();
        }
        if (fd0[0] != STDIN_FILENO) {
            close(fd0[0]);
        }
        if (fd1[1] != STDOUT_FILENO) {
            close(fd0[1]);
        }
        fd0[0] = fd1[0];
        fd0[1] = fd1[1];
        fd1[0] = fd1[1] = -1;
    }
    if (myList->next) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: MAX_PIPE_LEN (%d) is too small\n",
                MAX_PIPE_LEN);
    }

    if (fd0[0] >= 0 && fd0[0] != STDIN_FILENO) {
        close(fd0[0]);
    }
    if (fd0[1] >= 0 && fd0[1] != STDOUT_FILENO) {
        close(fd0[1]);
    }
    if (fd1[0] >= 0) {
        close(fd1[0]);
    }
    if (fd1[1] >= 0 && fd1[1] != STDOUT_FILENO) {
        close(fd1[1]);
    }
    /* Now wait for the commands to finish */
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < pipe_len; i++) {
        if (waitpid(pids[pipe_len - 1], &status, 0) == -1) {
            perror("error: waitpid failed");
            failed = 1;
        }
    }
    if (failed)
        status = -1;
    myshell_exit(status);
}
```

Comment: How would solve this problem?. I have looked at too many tutorial and still can't find the right way to do this.

Comment: Let me have a look…

Comment: I already found a solution online. I will post it, but still I have a problem; however, I think debugging the new solution will be easier.

Comment: You check mine ;-)

Comment: Thank you !!, before this claim , I think you meant another word instead of fd if (myList->next) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: MAX_PIPE_LEN (%d) is too small\n",
                MAX_PIPE_LEN);

Comment: Exact. I corrected it. Keep your eye open for more mistakes: I did not test the code B-)